# jQuery: how can I select only the checkboxes that are visible and checked?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check whether or not all the visible check boxes in a certain series are checked  and i thought of just counting those that are visible and those that are visible and checked to see if the numbers are the same. The problem is I can't get the visible nor the checked selectors to work.

These are some of the ideas I had but didn't work:

```
if($j("input[id^='chk_camp']:visible:checked").length == $j("input[id^='chk_camp']:visible").length)
```

both sides are 0 in this case

```
if($j("input[id^='chk_camp']").filter(':visible').filter(':checked').length == $j("input[id^='chk_camp']").filter(':visible').length)
```

also returned 0 on both sides.

Also tried

```
if($j("input[id^='chk_camp'][visible][checked]").length == $j("input[id^='chk_camp'][visible]").length)
```

and this also returns 0 on both sides.

As a note `$j("input[id^='chk_camp']").length` returns the correct value. Also the browser I'm working with is Firefox.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer: Aparently what I'm doing wrong is somewhere else. I was doing these checks before actually making the div containing the checkboxes visible so all the visibility checks were returning false.

Comment: The code works correctly for me. Look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/yerpm/1/). Maybe you made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @NOX Yes I did do something wrong. I did the checks before i made the container div visible so they obviously returned false on the visible check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/aUFuT/)**

jQuery:

```
$('input').each(function() {

    // If input is visible and checked...
    if ( $(this).is(':visible') && $(this).prop('checked') ) {

        $(this).wrap('<div />');

    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox">
```

CSS:

```
div { float: left; background: green; }
div input { display: block !important; }
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as this is a good solution for when the selectors actually wouldn't work. Even tho my particular problem was elsewhere, your answer would have been valid if the selectors were actually at fault.

Answer (score 10):

This works fine for me.

```
$(".inputClass:checked:visible");
$(".inputClass:checked:visible").length;
```

OR adapting the above answer.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUFuT/3/)**

```
$('input:visible:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div />');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
if($j("input[id^='chk_camp']").filter(':visible').filter(':checked).length == $j("input[id^='chk_camp']).filter(':visible').length)
//                                                          ------^------ missing qoutes here      ----^--- also double quotes here
```

Comment: misstype, sorry. Thanks for the heads up, i'll fix it right away.

Comment: @Bogdan: Code seems to be working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hN28E/). Make sure the checkbox id is correct.

Comment: uh well this is embarassing. They do indeed work, the problem was that I was doing all the checking before I actually made the container div visible, so of course they all returned 0 since none of them were visible at the time...

Comment: @Bogdan Dunno how you figured that out, but in situations where something should work but it doesn't seem to do so, I usually turn to  `console.log()`. and check the selectors to see what they say separately, for example: `console.log( $(this).is(':visible') );`

Comment: Yeah I did that, that's how I know what each part of the if condition returned. I just thought it had something to do with the :visible selector being iffy.